# How to structure Django project and implement views into index.html

Tags: python, django, api, frontend

I have my frontend set up using html and css. Now I would like to use Python/Django to make http requests on a third party API (views.py) and return the data to my html containers within the index.html site which represents my dashboard. My goal is to enable the user to choose the soccer team of his choice within the sidebar to update the dashboard with the according data that is sourced via third party API and manipulated via Python afterwards before displaying it on the frontend.

Is there any way to do this or do I have to change my entire frontend development to python/django now? (since I can't find any resource/tutorial that suggest to link views.py functions to .html files).

Still trying to figure out how these spheres are connected to each other.

This is my current project setup:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D6Pl.jpg)

Any hints are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't at all understand what you mean by "I can't find any resource/tutorial that suggest to link views.py functions to .html files". That is literally covered in *every* tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is a web development framework where you can front and back together.

You can make requests with Ajax for Django and use the values in your HTML page.
The correct thing is that you use Django templates, which is your HTML.

You can read more about Django project / app creation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/